# How do I encrypt an app with the device's pin as the key on an unencrypted Anroid phone?

Tags: encryption, android

For users who do not have whole disk encryption enabled on their phone I'd like to encrypt the apps files myself with the user's device password/pin.

I do not want the user to have an additional password when accessing our app. We currently only support phones with Android 5 that have a device pincode/password set.

I'd like this to operate in a similar manner to the iOS `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` where the apps data will remain encrypted until the user authenticates their phone for the first time. Having it encrypted whenever their phone is locked would also be desirable.

Is this possible and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this for your own applications, or are you asking as a device administrator that wishes to protect 3rd party apps?

Comment: @SilverlightFox My own app.